# Check if a row exists before SELECTing

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have to display a list of employees, but the display of the list depends on the status of the logged in user. If I'm your supervisor, I may see you in my list.

But I wish to check if you exists in my `LeaveRequest` table before SELECTing you to display you.

I have tried the following with no success :

```
string sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = '" + employee + "')";
       sql += " SELECT ActivityTypeId FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = '" + employee + "'";
```

Otherwise :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = 'chris')
  SELECT ActivityTypeId FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = 'chris'
```

Let's say that chris does not exists at all in the table LeaveRequest, (no row with Login = 'chris'), it will give me a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With exception details that are not precise.

How may I simply check and skip if the user is not found in the table?

EDIT: I shall use parametrized queries for security reasons later on.

EDIT2: The error appears once I do the following to save the data selected :

```
 string sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = '" + employee + "')";
                sql += " SELECT ActivityTypeId FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = '" + employee + "'";

                mDB_DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, m_strConnectionString);
                mDB_DataAdapter.Fill(mDB_DataSet, "LeaveRequest");
                mDB_DataAdapter = null;

                string str = (mDB_DataSet.Tables["LeaveRequest"].Rows[0][0]).ToString(); // Right here
```

Comment: I checked your concern, every thing looks good, might be issue with datatype or data of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rows = mDB_DataSet.Tables["LeaveRequest"].Rows;
var str = rows.Count > 0 ? rows[0]["ActivityTypeId"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

and remove "IF EXISTS..." from sql

```
var sql = " SELECT ActivityTypeId FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = '" + employee + "'";
```

sure remake this to parametrized view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is not the exact answer, But I am sharing a very nice suggestion or idea that might help you.

```
If it is a checks between 2 tables only So better try using join, union all etc between the tables.
```

As you shared query:-

> SELECT 1 FROM LeaveRequest WHERE Login = 'chris'

if chris not exist in database at, query will never through exception. Please recheck again, might be you missing something.